# Laravel (ErrorException(code: 0): Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel, web, stripe-payments

I am currently trying to integrate the Stripe payment system with invoicing to my Laravel-based web appliation.

However, while testing the payment model an Internal Server 500 error message appeared.

After looking at the Laravel logs, I identied that an ErrorException code was generated as follows:

local.ERROR: Creating default object from empty value {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Creating default object from empty value .

The line of code this error referred to  is as follows:

> $paymentHistory->payment_intent_id = $payment_intent;

I tried executing and rolling back the existing migration scripts to see if that would remedy the issue but still was unsuccessful.

If anybody has encountered a similar issue like this before, I would greatly appreciate any possible solutions.

Comment: `$paymentHistory` is apparently not an object, most likely null. Check to see where it's being created

Comment: A property assignment is not a constructor call ... and `HTTP500` is not an error description. Maybe just use `xdebug`, alike everybody else?

Comment: as aynber said you are assigning a property to something that isn't an object (`null` or `''`, null equivalents)  PHP will create a default object (`stdClass` object) so that it can assign the property to it (depending on the PHP version) https://3v4l.org/8DkKC  you can see that warning/error with PHP 7.3.0-7.4.27 for that paste